# Google/Apple billing APIs: How to know what Apple/Google ID did a purchase?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, uuid, billing

I have a significant problem concerning the billing APIs of Apple and Google (i.e. iOS and Android).

My app has its own user account handling so that the user can switch the device or have multiple devices with data in sync. If it's important: it's a cordova app, but I think the problem is of more general nature.

Now the user can purchase an auto renewing subscription which is (of course) implemented using the APIs of Apple and Google.

The problem is the following situation (for the sake of simplicity only described for Apple, but issue is the same for Android):

1. User with AppleID X signs in with his account A.
2. He purchases the auto renewing subscription (obviously with AppleID X) while being logged into his account A. Now account A has the benefit of the subscription.
3. Now he uninstalls the app and reinstalls it.
4. He logs into another account B and restores the purchase. Now also account B has the benefit of the subscription.

How can I avoid this which is a major flaw? How can my server identify which AppleID (or Google ID) is linked to which purchase?

A simple way would be to read out the UUID of the user but I know this is not allowed.

Do you have any experience on how to fix the issue? Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use the receipt identifier for the subscription purchase and link it to "account A" on your server. Then, when Account B tries to restore the purchase you check your server database and find that that purchase is already linked to account A.  At this point you can either delink it and turn off account A's access or return an error to the user.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "receipt identifier" (is this referencing apple or google?)? Maybe I could also use the transaction_id in the receipt data and attach it to the user? For Android I just found the "developerPayload" item. I pass the email address of the user to this field and so I can check on validation if the field matches the current user trying to restore purchases. But in fact I could also use the transaction id, or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to ios. You can use the "original_transaction_identifier" field from the receipt. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1 I don't know about Android.

Comment: OK, and what about the "receipt identifier"? Did you mean the token I use for validation?

Comment: Sorry, by receipt identifier I meant "an identifier from the receipt". I hadn't looked up the actual field name at that point.

Comment: @The_Unknown did you come up with a solution for this? I have a related issue - if you have a user syncing data across their two Apple IDs, how can you check if the subscription has lapsed?

Comment: @Giles Yep, I did. On Android you can use a string called "developerPayload". You set that to the username/email of the user while he subscribes and check that while he restores his purchases. Sadly (and for unknown reasons) Apple didn't add such a feature to the Billing API. Here I decided to extract the "original_transaction_id" from the validation receipt and store that in my server backend. When the user restores purchases, I check if the "original_transaction_id" is in the user object of the user currently logged in. Hope I could help. For me the whole billing topic was much pain ;-)

Comment: Thank you @The_Unknown. It does sound awkward. I think I am going to have to make App Store checks from my backend to check receipts.

Comment: In fact the solution is quite simple. On subscribe() just add the original transaction id to the user currently logged into your app. When restoring purchased, just check in your backend if the original transaction id from the purchase just being restored is stored in the user object currently logged into your app. Voila :-) If you find a simpler solution it would be awesome if you could post it here!